# Can not persist null values (nullable=true)

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I need to insert a null value, instead of empty string into my H2-Database.
My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Link extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5337989744648444109L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "title is required")
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = true)
    private String url;
}
```

and my sql-statment with values, which will be generated from Hibernate looks like

> ```
> insert 
> into
>     link
>     (link_id, created_by, creation_date, title, url) 
> values
>     (null, ?, ?, ?, ?,) -
>             session_id=2B491C6BFFE4F66BD63C6453E234D991 user_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2022-12-21 14:21:21,232 |
> ```
>
> https-jsse-nio-5550-exec-9 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding
> parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZciTc.png) as [VARCHAR] - [mymail@test.com] -
> session_id=2B491C6BFFE4F66BD63C6453E234D991 user_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2022-12-21 14:21:21,232 |
> https-jsse-nio-5550-exec-9 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding
> parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-12-21T14:21:21.231038300] -
> session_id=2B491C6BFFE4F66BD63C6453E234D991 user_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2022-12-21 14:21:21,233 |
> https-jsse-nio-5550-exec-9 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding
> parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Tessst] -
> session_id=2B491C6BFFE4F66BD63C6453E234D991 user_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 2022-12-21 14:21:21,233 |
> https-jsse-nio-5550-exec-9 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder | binding
> parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null] -
> session_id=2B491C6BFFE4F66BD63C6453E234D991 user_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

The  last parameter [4] will be filled with null value, but i still have in my H2-Database empty string.

[image: H2-Console]

I've tested, that i can insert manually null values into this column with naitve sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

As i've updated SpringBoot from 2.4.5 to 2.7.7, i don't have this bug anymore